# Definition of multivariable function classes doubt

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I was given this example by my teacher:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & (x,y) = 0 \\
      \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4 + y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\
   \end{cases}
$

He proved diferentiablity for all $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then he went to prove wether the function was class $C^1$ or not. He used $y=x^2$ to prove it wasn't. And that's what put me in doubt.

Doesn't diferentiability in $\mathbb{R}^2$ imply it's partial derivatives are continuous, therefore $C^1$. Am I missing something in this example?

Comment: Continuity and differentiability are checked in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1045593/26369) to another question, but this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @MarkS. It does.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, differentiability does *not* imply that the partial derivatives are continuous (it's the other way around). Take, for instance$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks, so to check if a function is class $C^1$ I have only to worry about continuity of partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.